# if statement won't reset with each iteration of for loop

Tags: r, loops

To run this function, the csv file,outcome-of-care-measures.csv, can be found at https://github.com/Bheal/Board-Q-A. 
This post only concerns this portion of the code used inside the loop in my function below:

```
if(num=="best"){num=1}
if(num=="worst") {num=nrow(df); print(num)}
```

I have put this function together.  I had an idea(novice, I am) of what to do but at almost each step something needed to be tweaked to get the desired function.
But my one remaining hurdle is that I cannot seem to add an element to my loop such that if-statment assigns new value to variable `num` (if num="worst" is the function input).
(see below `# ***`)

```
rankall <- function( outcome, num = "best") {
        ## Read outcome data
        tmp <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv",na.strings="Not Available")

                b1 <- outcome %in% c("heart attack","heart failure","pneumonia")

        # if(){stop()}
        if(b1==FALSE){ stop("Invaled output name")}

        if(outcome=="heart attack") {i=11}
        if(outcome=="heart failure") {i=17}
        if(outcome=="pneumonia") {i=23}

        t1<-as.vector(unique(tmp[['State']]))

        #initialize a df for storage        
        dfall<- data.frame("H.name"=as.character(), "S.name"=as.character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


        for(x in 1:length(t1)) {                                # begin a loop, each state abb.

                df <- subset(tmp, State==t1[x], select= c(2,i)) # subset data.frame, for state abb., & select column with Hospital name & i(outcome col).
                df <- subset(df, !is.na(df[2]))                 # remove rows with na's in the outcome col from this data.frame.

# *** *** ***

print(dim(df))  # *** for each loop the dim(df) function is reset, but I can't get the num below in the to reset using the if statement.
        # *** However if 

                if(num=="best"){num=1}
                if(num=="worst") {num=nrow(df); print(num)}     # ***   this only prints one time, and is equal to the no. of rows in df from the first loop.
# *** *** ***

                df <- df[order(df[2],df[1]), ]                  # order this data.frame. by outcome(primary) and Hosptial(secondary).

                df[[1]] <- as.character(df[[1]])                # Class of First column of df changed: was class factor, changed to class char.


                entry <- c(df[num,1],t1[x])

                dfall <- rbind(dfall,entry, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)   # ? I have to use stringsAsFactors=FALSE, else dfall won't populate properly.

        }

  names(dfall) <- c("Hospital", "State")          # ? If I don not assign these names, d.f. dfall has wrong names(tied to 1st entry), not H.name,S.name. 
  return(dfall)
}
```

My reliance on `num`works if it equal an integer in the function call, but in case of `num`="worst" I need to pull a particular numbered entry for each iteration.  (If `num`="best" that dose not effect the results, since that corresponds to the first row in each iteration). 
**WHY are the if statements not effected by each iteration of for loop?** df is being reset in each loop and `dim(df)` changes too as evidenced by the output of `print(dim(df))` below

```
if(num=="best"){num=1}
if(num=="worst") {num=nrow(df); print(num)}
```

As seen in the output the 2nd row give prints 91 (and then num=91 is used in the remaining loops if num="worst" in the function call)

```
> rankall("pneumonia", "worst")
[1] 91  2
[1] 91
[1] 14  2
[1] 65  2
[1] 73  2
        .
        .
        .
        .
                                            Hospital State
1                    JACKSONVILLE MEDICAL CENTER    AL
2                                           <NA>    AK
3                                           <NA>    AZ
4                                           <NA>    AR
5                        MARINA DEL REY HOSPITAL    CA
6                                           <NA>    CO
.
.
.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i would recommend adjusting the ordering `if(num=="worst")` instead of trying to grab a numeric location. `df <- df[order(df[2], df[1], decreasing = T), ]`

Comment: Sorry I don't follow, but to reiterate my problem, I am trying to replace `num` when it is equated to worst in the function call with last row of said data.frame, and was hoping to use if statement inside a for-loop to do so.

Comment: It is because you overwrite `num`. In the first iteration you have, say, `num="worst"` and the you replace it with a number. In the second iteration `num` is a value and thus none of your criteria are matched

Comment: I see, so `num` becomes an integer and remains so, that gives me something to think about thanks a ton.

Comment: Please use 2 spaces per indent-level when you post code here on SO, rather than the full PEP-8-compliant 8 spaces. Also, max 72-80 chars per line. Your code is impossible to read and your long comments are all truncated off the RHS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (just to show what I meant by my comment). You want to keep the `num` argument given in the function call and use that for each iteration. I've added a reset in the code below.

```
rankall2 <- function( outcome, num = "best") {
    ## Read outcome data
    tmp <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv",na.strings="Not Available")

    b1 <- outcome %in% c("heart attack","heart failure","pneumonia")

    # if(){stop()}
    if(b1==FALSE){ stop("Invaled output name")}

    if(outcome=="heart attack") {i=11}
    if(outcome=="heart failure") {i=17}
    if(outcome=="pneumonia") {i=23}

    t1<-as.vector(unique(tmp[['State']]))

    #initialize a df for storage        
    dfall<- data.frame("H.name"=as.character(), "S.name"=as.character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    ## Keep the original num
    original.num <- num 

    for(x in 1:length(t1)) {                                # begin a loop, each state abb.
        ## Reset num
        num <- original.num

        df <- subset(tmp, State==t1[x], select= c(2,i)) # subset data.frame, for state abb., & select column with Hospital name & i(outcome col).
        df <- subset(df, !is.na(df[2]))                 # remove rows with na's in the outcome col from this data.frame.

# *** *** ***

        print(dim(df))  # *** for each loop the dim(df) function is reset, but I can't get the num below in the to reset using the if statement.
        # *** However if 

        if(num=="best"){num=1}
        if(num=="worst") {num=nrow(df); print(num)}     # ***   this only prints one time, and is equal to the no. of rows in df from the first loop.
# *** *** ***

        df <- df[order(df[2],df[1]), ]                  # order this data.frame. by outcome(primary) and Hosptial(secondary).

        df[[1]] <- as.character(df[[1]])                # Class of First column of df changed: was class factor, changed to class char.

        entry <- c(df[num,1],t1[x])

        dfall <- rbind(dfall,entry, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)   # ? I have to use stringsAsFactors=FALSE, else dfall won't populate properly.

    }

    names(dfall) <- c("Hospital", "State")          # ? If I don not assign these names, d.f. dfall has wrong names(tied to 1st entry), not H.name,S.name. 
    return(dfall)
}
```

Comment: I' ll pay attention in the future, I am sure there are other ways to improve but, that solves this one.  Thanks again.